# disable radio button based on other radio button's value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have four radio buttons(1,2,3,4). 3 and 4 radio buttons should be disabled when 1 is selected. When 2 is selected, 3 and 4 should be enabled again.

I am using a library for accordion and it uses `ng-transclude`. When the page loads I check radiobutton1 by default. So 3 and 4 are disabled. When I selected radiobutton2, 3 and 4 are enabled. But when I select radiobutton1 again, 3 and 4 are not disabled.

I use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj?hl=en) to check `$scope` variables and there's a new variable attached to `$scope` with the same name under `ngTransclude`(new variable which is under scope of the transclusion) and there is the original variable under the controller's scope which still has the `ng-model` value of the radio button.

The copy of `type` under `transclude` is still `'expense'`.  I use `ng-disabled="type!='expense'"` and the `scope.type` under transclude is still `'expense'` when I click on the other radio button. So the radio buttons are not getting disabled?

How do I make it work?

```
 <div class="form-check">
       <input type="radio" ng-model="maintenance_bill_rate_type" value="1">
       <label>Fixed Per Flat</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
       <input type="radio" ng-model="type" value="2">
       <label>Expenses</label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <label>
       <input type="radio" ng-model="maintenance_bill_rate_type" 
         ng-disabled="type!='expense'"
          value="3">
       </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
       <label>
       <input type="radio" name="optradio" ng- 
        model="maintenance_bill_rate_type" value="4" 
        ng-disabled="type!='expense'" >
       </label>
    </div>
```

In the inspector I see two `type` variables(which is used to disabled 3 and 4 radio buttons), one under controller's scope and one under transclude scope.

This works when I'm not using the library for accordion.

Comment: Use checkbox instead of radio buttons

Comment: @sridhar..i think the problem is the transclude creates a separate scope. I use `ng-disabled="type!='expense'"` and the `scope.type` under transclude is still `'expense'` when I click on the other radio button

Comment: Try using object in ng-model something like `$scope.data.maintenance_bill_rate_type` and so on for all `$scope` and let me know. so it would be like `ng-model="data.maintenance_bill_rate_type"` and so on

Answer (score 1):

radio button works inside form tag so you have to add form first and you have to do some changes in the ng-model name refer this.

```
<form>
   <div class="form-check" >
     <input type="radio" ng-model="radioMain" value="1">
     <label>Fixed Per Flat</label>
   </div>
   <div class="form-check">
     <input type="radio" ng-model="radioMain" value="2">
     <label>Expenses</label>
   </div>
   <div class="row">

     <div class="col-md-3">
       <label>
         <input type="radio" ng-model="maintenance_bill_rate_type" 
            ng-disabled="radioMain==1" value="3">
       </label>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <label>
         <input type="radio" ng-model="maintenance_bill_rate_type" 
         ng-disabled="radioMain==1" value="4">
       </label>
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i think you mean have the same variable for ng-model was the problem, but i didn't fully say what I'm doing in the question. I change the `type` when i click the other radio. it worked when i attached all variables to an object

Comment: sorry I didn't get what you actually want?

Answer (score 0):

try this code. This will work for your requirement.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // By Default Disable radio button
    $(".second").attr('disabled', true);
    $(".wrap").css('opacity', '.2'); // This line is used to lightly hide 
          label for disable radio buttons.
    // Disable radio buttons function on Check Disable radio button.
    $("form input:radio").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Disable") {
    $(".second").attr('checked', false);
    $(".second").attr('disabled', true);
    $(".wrap").css('opacity', '.2');
    }
    // Else Enable radio buttons.
    else {
    $(".second").attr('disabled', false);
    $(".wrap").css('opacity', '1');
    }
    });
    });
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif);
    h2{
    text-align: center;
    }
    hr{
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    }
    div.container{
    width: 643px;
    margin:50px auto;
    font-family: 'Droid Serif', serif;
    position:relative;
    }
    div.main{
    width: 320px;
    padding: 10px 60px 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0 auto 50px;
    }
    span{
    margin-right: 17px;
    font-size: 15px;
    }
    input[type=radio]{
    margin:10px 10px 0 10px;
    }
    label{
    color: #464646;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
         <head>
         <title>Disable Radio Button in Form Using jQuery</title>
         <!-- Include CSS File Here -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        <!-- Include JS File Here -->
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> 
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="disable_radio.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div class="container">
        <div class="main">
         <h2>Disable Radio Button in Form Using jQuery</h2>
         <form action="#" method="post" id="form">
        <label>Enable / Disable Radio Buttons: </label>
        <input type="radio" name="first" value="Enable" id="enable">
        <span>Enable</span>
        <input type="radio" name="first" value="Disable" id="disable" checked>
        <span>Disable</span>
         <label>Radio Buttons :</label>
         <input type="radio" name="second" class="second" value="Radio 1">
           <span class="wrap">Radio 1</span>
           <input type="radio" name="second" class="second" value="Radio 2">
         <span class="wrap">Radio 2</span>
      <input type="radio" name="second" class="second" value="Radio 3">
      <span class="wrap">Radio 3</span>
      </form>
      </div>
      </div>
      </body>
      </html>
```